# using cmake to make a library without sse support (windows version)

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, illegal-instruction

I want to setup OpenCV using CMake for Visual Studio 2019. After all these processes while debugging my program I get this error:

**Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCF1FF2382 (opencv_world412d.dll) in yaabolfazl.exe: 0xC000001D: Illegal Instruction. occurred.**

I think it is caused by my processor which can not support  AVX (Windows 8.1, core i5 M520 2.4GHz). (Am I right?)
I found out I can make a new version of OpenCV using CMake without AVX support by using `CPU_DISPATCH` and `CPU_BASELINE` option, but when I change their value I get this error:

**Error in the configuration process, project file may be invalid.**

So how can I build OpenCV using CMake without AVX support(e.g. using SSE support only)?

My CMake configuration
[image: My cmake configuration]

CPU instruction set:
[image: CPU-Z]

Comment: To answer your embedded question: No your [CPU does not have AVX](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i5/Intel-Core%20i5%20Mobile%20I5-520M%20CP80617004119AE%20%28BX80617I5520M%29.html).

Comment: We need to see a more detailed error message.

Comment: I assume you've downloaded the OpenCV source package; go to the "<opencv_folder>\cmake\" folder and open "OpenCVCompilerOptimizations.cmake". Search for these two lines: "ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_AVX AVX ON)
ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_AVX2 AVX2 ON)" If you set it to OFF, does it help?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your replay. I added one a screenshot  . what else do u need?

Comment: you can also try setting the -DENABLE_AVX=OFF and -DENABLE_AVX2=OFF when making OpenCV with cmake. I don't use the CMake GUI, but in command line it looks something like this: cmake -DENABLE_AVX=OFF -DENABLE_AVX2=OFF -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" ..  (asuming you have cmake in your PATH and execute this command from a created build folder inside the opencv folder)

Comment: @Zoltán thanks for your answer.  there is no line named "ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option" and ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_AVX2 AVX2 ON) ..

Comment: am I right? for  Illegal Instruction error, I have to turn avx off? my CPU : intel corei5 @Zoltán

Comment: AVX is supperted on Sandy Bridge (2011) and above Intel processors, according to wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions If this is your processor: https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/47341/intel-core-i5-520m-processor-3m-cache-2-40-ghz.html it is from 2010, so AVX probably not supported as @nada pointed out. It is probably an issue, but I've never faced something like this before.

Comment: @Zoltán may u see my question in detail?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57959602/trouble-with-setting-up-opencv-4-1-1-on-visual-microsoft-studio-2019-illega

Comment: Have you tried building OpenCV as I suggested in the previous answer? If you need a detailed description, I can do that. If you send me your e-mail address so we don't spam here.

Comment: @Zoltán thanks hamidrezaar@gmail.com

Comment: Ran into the exact same issue (Windows 8.1, i520, VS2019, too) even with the just released OpenCV 4.1.2 and decided to file an [issue at their GitHub repository](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15690).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem most likely is that your CPU doesn't support some CPU features (like AVX) that OpenCV uses. I'm not sure what are the exact CMake flags to disable these features when building OpenCV, but there is another way to solve this (the brute-force way :D). Download the OpenCV sources from  [this link](https://opencv.org/releases/) and unzip it (the current latest version is 4.1.1).
Go to the *opencv-4.1.1\cmake* folder and open *OpenCVCompilerOptimizations.cmake* in a text editor. It contains optimizations for different CPU architecture. The screenshot attached in the question shows the supported instructions by your CPU. In the *OpenCVCompilerOptimizations.cmake* file simply remove (or comment out) every instruction options that are not supported by your CPU. Here is my version (I only include the first half of the file where the modifications are. Compare it with the original to see the differences):

```
# x86/x86-64 arch:
# SSE / SSE2 (always available on 64-bit CPUs)
# SSE3 / SSSE3
# SSE4_1 / SSE4_2 / POPCNT
# AVX / AVX2 / AVX_512F
# FMA3
#
# CPU features groups:
# AVX512_COMMON (Common instructions AVX-512F/CD for all CPUs that support AVX-512)
# AVX512_KNL (Knights Landing with AVX-512F/CD/ER/PF)
# AVX512_KNM (Knights Mill with AVX-512F/CD/ER/PF/4FMAPS/4VNNIW/VPOPCNTDQ)
# AVX512_SKX (Skylake-X with AVX-512F/CD/BW/DQ/VL)
# AVX512_CNL (Cannon Lake with AVX-512F/CD/BW/DQ/VL/IFMA/VBMI)
# AVX512_CEL (Cascade Lake with AVX-512F/CD/BW/DQ/VL/IFMA/VBMI/VNNI)
# AVX512_ICL (Ice Lake with AVX-512F/CD/BW/DQ/VL/IFMA/VBMI/VNNI/VBMI2/BITALG/VPOPCNTDQ/VPCLMULQDQ*/GFNI*/VAES*)

# ppc64le arch:
# VSX  (always available on Power8)
# VSX3 (always available on Power9)

# CPU_{opt}_SUPPORTED=ON/OFF - compiler support (possibly with additional flag)
# CPU_{opt}_IMPLIES=<list>
# CPU_{opt}_FORCE=<list> - subset of "implies" list
# CPU_{opt}_GROUP=<list> - similar to "implies" list, but additionally merges compiler flags
# CPU_{opt}_FLAGS_ON=""
# CPU_{opt}_FEATURE_ALIAS - mapping to CV_CPU_* HWFeature enum

# Input variables:
# CPU_BASELINE=<list> - preferred list of baseline optimizations
# CPU_DISPATCH=<list> - preferred list of dispatched optimizations

# Advanced input variables:
# CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE=<list> - list of required baseline optimizations
# CPU_DISPATCH_REQUIRE=<list> - list of required dispatched optimizations
# CPU_BASELINE_DISABLE=<list> - list of disabled baseline optimizations

# Output variables:
# CPU_BASELINE_FINAL=<list> - final list of enabled compiler optimizations
# CPU_DISPATCH_FINAL=<list> - final list of dispatched optimizations
#
# CPU_DISPATCH_FLAGS_${opt} - flags for source files compiled separately (<name>.avx2.cpp)
#
# CPU_{opt}_ENABLED_DEFAULT=ON/OFF - has compiler support without additional flag (CPU_BASELINE_DETECT=ON only)

set(CPU_ALL_OPTIMIZATIONS "SSE;SSE2;SSE3;SSSE3;SSE4_1;SSE4_2")
##list(APPEND CPU_ALL_OPTIMIZATIONS "AVX512_COMMON;AVX512_KNL;AVX512_KNM;AVX512_SKX;AVX512_CNL;AVX512_CEL;AVX512_ICL")
##list(APPEND CPU_ALL_OPTIMIZATIONS NEON VFPV3 FP16)
##list(APPEND CPU_ALL_OPTIMIZATIONS VSX VSX3)
list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES CPU_ALL_OPTIMIZATIONS)

ocv_update(CPU_VFPV3_FEATURE_ALIAS "")


set(HELP_CPU_BASELINE "Specify list of enabled baseline CPU optimizations")
set(HELP_CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE "Specify list of required baseline CPU optimizations")
set(HELP_CPU_BASELINE_DISABLE "Specify list of forbidden baseline CPU optimizations")
set(HELP_CPU_DISPATCH "Specify list of dispatched CPU optimizations")
set(HELP_CPU_DISPATCH_REQUIRE "Specify list of required dispatched CPU optimizations")

foreach(var CPU_BASELINE CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE CPU_BASELINE_DISABLE CPU_DISPATCH CPU_DISPATCH_REQUIRE)
  if(DEFINED ${var})
    string(REPLACE "," ";" _list "${${var}}")
    set(${var} "${_list}" CACHE STRING "${HELP_${var}}" FORCE)
  endif()
endforeach()

# process legacy flags
macro(ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option legacy_flag OPT legacy_warn)
  if(DEFINED "${legacy_flag}")
    if("${legacy_warn}")
      message(STATUS "WARNING: Option ${legacy_flag}='${${legacy_flag}}' is deprecated and should not be used anymore")
      message(STATUS "         Behaviour of this option is not backward compatible")
      message(STATUS "         Refer to 'CPU_BASELINE'/'CPU_DISPATCH' CMake options documentation")
    endif()
    if("${${legacy_flag}}")
      if(NOT ";${CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE};" MATCHES ";${OPT};")
        set(CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE "${CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE};${OPT}" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_BASELINE_REQUIRE}" FORCE)
      endif()
    else()
      if(NOT ";${CPU_BASELINE_DISABLE};" MATCHES ";${OPT};")
        set(CPU_BASELINE_DISABLE "${CPU_BASELINE_DISABLE};${OPT}" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_BASELINE_DISABLE}" FORCE)
      endif()
    endif()
  endif()
endmacro()
ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_SSE SSE ON)
ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_SSE2 SSE2 ON)
ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_SSE3 SSE3 ON)
ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_SSSE3 SSSE3 ON)
ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_SSE41 SSE4_1 ON)
ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_SSE42 SSE4_2 ON)
# ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_POPCNT POPCNT ON)
# ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_AVX AVX OFF)
# ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_AVX2 AVX2 OFF)
#ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_FMA3 FMA3 ON)

# ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_VFPV3 VFPV3 OFF)
# ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_NEON NEON OFF)

# ocv_optimization_process_obsolete_option(ENABLE_VSX VSX ON)

macro(ocv_is_optimization_in_list resultvar check_opt)
  set(__checked "")
  set(__queue ${ARGN})
  set(${resultvar} 0)
  while(__queue AND NOT ${resultvar})
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES __queue)
    set(__queue_current ${__queue})
    set(__queue "")
    foreach(OPT ${__queue_current})
      if("x${OPT}" STREQUAL "x${check_opt}")
        set(${resultvar} 1)
        break()
      elseif(NOT ";${__checked};" MATCHES ";${OPT};")
        list(APPEND __queue ${CPU_${OPT}_IMPLIES})
      endif()
      list(APPEND __checked ${OPT})
    endforeach()
  endwhile()
endmacro()

macro(ocv_is_optimization_in_force_list resultvar check_opt)
  set(__checked "")
  set(__queue ${ARGN})
  set(${resultvar} 0)
  while(__queue AND NOT ${resultvar})
    list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES __queue)
    set(__queue_current ${__queue})
    set(__queue "")
    foreach(OPT ${__queue_current})
      if(OPT STREQUAL "${check_opt}")
        set(${resultvar} 1)
        break()
      elseif(NOT ";${__checked};" MATCHES ";${OPT};")
        list(APPEND __queue ${CPU_${OPT}_FORCE})
      endif()
      list(APPEND __checked ${OPT})
    endforeach()
  endwhile()
endmacro()

macro(ocv_append_optimization_flag var OPT)
  if(CPU_${OPT}_FLAGS_CONFLICT)
    string(REGEX REPLACE " ${CPU_${OPT}_FLAGS_CONFLICT}" "" ${var} " ${${var}} ")
    string(REGEX REPLACE "^ +" "" ${var} "${${var}}")
  endif()
  set(${var} "${${var}} ${CPU_${OPT}_FLAGS_ON}")
endmacro()

# Support GCC -march=native or Intel Compiler -xHost flags
if(";${CPU_BASELINE};" MATCHES ";NATIVE;" OR ";${CPU_BASELINE};" MATCHES ";HOST;")
  set(CPU_BASELINE_DETECT ON)
  set(_add_native_flag ON)
elseif(";${CPU_BASELINE};" MATCHES ";DETECT;")
  set(CPU_BASELINE_DETECT ON)
elseif(" ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} " MATCHES " -march=native | -xHost | /QxHost ")
  if(DEFINED CPU_BASELINE)
    message(STATUS "CPU: Detected '-march=native' or '-xHost' compiler flag. Force CPU_BASELINE=DETECT.")
  endif()
  set(CPU_BASELINE "DETECT" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_BASELINE}")
  set(CPU_BASELINE_DETECT ON)
endif()

if(X86 OR X86_64)
  ocv_update(CPU_KNOWN_OPTIMIZATIONS "SSE;SSE2;SSE3;SSSE3;SSE4_1;SSE4_2")

  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_COMMON_GROUP "AVX_512F;AVX_512CD")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_KNL_GROUP "AVX512_COMMON;AVX512_KNL_EXTRA")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_KNM_GROUP "AVX512_KNL;AVX512_KNM_EXTRA;AVX_512VPOPCNTDQ")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_SKX_GROUP "AVX512_COMMON;AVX_512VL;AVX_512BW;AVX_512DQ")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_CNL_GROUP "AVX512_SKX;AVX_512IFMA;AVX_512VBMI")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_CEL_GROUP "AVX512_CNL;AVX_512VNNI")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_ICL_GROUP "AVX512_CEL;AVX_512VBMI2;AVX_512BITALG;AVX_512VPOPCNTDQ") # ? VPCLMULQDQ, GFNI, VAES

  ocv_update(CPU_SSE_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_sse.cpp")
  ocv_update(CPU_SSE2_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_sse2.cpp")
  ocv_update(CPU_SSE3_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_sse3.cpp")
  ocv_update(CPU_SSSE3_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_ssse3.cpp")
  ocv_update(CPU_SSE4_1_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_sse41.cpp")
  ocv_update(CPU_SSE4_2_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_sse42.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_POPCNT_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_popcnt.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX2_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx2.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_FP16_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_fp16.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512F_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx512.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_COMMON_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx512common.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_KNL_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx512knl.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_KNM_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx512knm.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_SKX_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx512skx.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_CNL_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx512cnl.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_CEL_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx512cel.cpp")
  # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_ICL_TEST_FILE "${OpenCV_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/checks/cpu_avx512icl.cpp")

  if(NOT OPENCV_CPU_OPT_IMPLIES_IGNORE)
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_ICL_IMPLIES "AVX512_CEL")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_CEL_IMPLIES "AVX512_CNL")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_CNL_IMPLIES "AVX512_SKX")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_SKX_IMPLIES "AVX512_COMMON")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_KNM_IMPLIES "AVX512_KNL")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_KNL_IMPLIES "AVX512_COMMON")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_COMMON_IMPLIES "AVX_512F")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512F_IMPLIES "AVX2")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512F_FORCE "") # Don't force other optimizations
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX2_IMPLIES "AVX;FMA3;FP16")
    # ocv_update(CPU_FMA3_IMPLIES "AVX2")
    # ocv_update(CPU_FMA3_FORCE "") # Don't force other optimizations
    # ocv_update(CPU_FP16_IMPLIES "AVX")
    # ocv_update(CPU_FP16_FORCE "") # Don't force other optimizations
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_IMPLIES "SSE4_2")
    ###ocv_update(CPU_SSE4_2_IMPLIES "SSE4_1;POPCNT")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE4_2_IMPLIES "SSE4_1")
    ocv_update(CPU_POPCNT_IMPLIES "SSE4_1")
    ocv_update(CPU_POPCNT_FORCE "") # Don't force other optimizations
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE4_1_IMPLIES "SSE3;SSSE3")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSSE3_IMPLIES "SSE3")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE3_IMPLIES "SSE2")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE2_IMPLIES "SSE")
  endif()

  if(CV_ICC)
    macro(ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option name unix_flags msvc_flags)
      ocv_update(CPU_${name}_FLAGS_NAME "${name}")
      if(MSVC)
        set(enable_flags "${msvc_flags}")
        set(flags_conflict "/arch:[^ ]*|/Qx:[^ ]+")
      else()
        set(enable_flags "${unix_flags}")
        set(flags_conflict "-msse[^ ]*|-mssse3|-mavx[^ ]*|-march[^ ]*|-x[^ ]+")
      endif()
      ocv_update(CPU_${name}_FLAGS_ON "${enable_flags}")
      if(flags_conflict)
        ocv_update(CPU_${name}_FLAGS_CONFLICT "${flags_conflict}")
      endif()
    endmacro()
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX2 "-march=core-avx2" "/arch:CORE-AVX2")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(FP16 "-mavx" "/arch:AVX")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX "-mavx" "/arch:AVX")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(FMA3 "" "")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(POPCNT "" "")
    ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(SSE4_2 "-msse4.2" "/arch:SSE4.2")
    ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(SSE4_1 "-msse4.1" "/arch:SSE4.1")
    ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(SSE3 "-msse3" "/arch:SSE3")
    ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(SSSE3 "-mssse3" "/arch:SSSE3")
    ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(SSE2 "-msse2" "/arch:SSE2")
    if(NOT X86_64) # x64 compiler doesn't support /arch:sse
      ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(SSE "-msse" "/arch:SSE")
    endif()
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX_512F "-xCOMMON-AVX512" "/Qx:COMMON-AVX512")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX512_COMMON "-xCOMMON-AVX512" "/Qx:COMMON-AVX512")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX512_KNL "-xKNL" "/Qx:KNL")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX512_KNM "-xKNM" "/Qx:KNM")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX512_SKX "-xSKYLAKE-AVX512" "/Qx:SKYLAKE-AVX512")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX512_CNL "-xCANNONLAKE" "/Qx:CANNONLAKE")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX512_CEL "-xCASCADELAKE" "/Qx:CASCADELAKE")
    # ocv_intel_compiler_optimization_option(AVX512_ICL "-xICELAKE-CLIENT" "/Qx:ICELAKE-CLIENT")
  elseif(CV_GCC OR CV_CLANG)
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX2_FLAGS_ON "-mavx2")
    # ocv_update(CPU_FP16_FLAGS_ON "-mf16c")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_FLAGS_ON "-mavx")
    # ocv_update(CPU_FMA3_FLAGS_ON "-mfma")
    # ocv_update(CPU_POPCNT_FLAGS_ON "-mpopcnt")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE4_2_FLAGS_ON "-msse4.2")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE4_1_FLAGS_ON "-msse4.1")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE3_FLAGS_ON "-msse3")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSSE3_FLAGS_ON "-mssse3")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE2_FLAGS_ON "-msse2")
    ocv_update(CPU_SSE_FLAGS_ON "-msse")
    # if(NOT (CV_GCC AND CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS "5.0"))  # GCC >= 5.0
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512F_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512f")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512CD_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512cd")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_KNL_EXTRA_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512er -mavx512pf")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX512_KNM_EXTRA_FLAGS_ON "-mavx5124fmaps -mavx5124vnniw")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512BW_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512bw")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512DQ_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512dq")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512VL_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512vl")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512IFMA_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512ifma")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512VBMI_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512vbmi")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512VNNI_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512vnni")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512VBMI2_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512vbmi2")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512BITALG_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512bitalg")
      # # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512VPOPCNTDQ_FLAGS_ON "-mavx512vpopcntdq")
    # else()
      # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512F_SUPPORTED OFF)
    # endif()
  elseif(MSVC)
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX2_FLAGS_ON "/arch:AVX2")
    # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_FLAGS_ON "/arch:AVX")
    # ocv_update(CPU_FP16_FLAGS_ON "/arch:AVX")
    if(NOT MSVC64)
      # 64-bit MSVC compiler uses SSE/SSE2 by default
      ocv_update(CPU_SSE_FLAGS_ON "/arch:SSE")
      ocv_update(CPU_SSE_SUPPORTED ON)
      ocv_update(CPU_SSE2_FLAGS_ON "/arch:SSE2")
      ocv_update(CPU_SSE2_SUPPORTED ON)
    else()
      ocv_update(CPU_SSE_SUPPORTED ON)
      ocv_update(CPU_SSE2_SUPPORTED ON)
      # ocv_update(CPU_AVX_512F_FLAGS_ON "/arch:AVX512")
    endif()
    # Other instruction sets are supported by default since MSVC 2008 at least
  else()
    message(WARNING "TODO: Unsupported compiler")
  endif()

  # if(NOT DEFINED CPU_DISPATCH)
    # if(X86_64)
      # set(CPU_DISPATCH "SSE4_1;SSE4_2;AVX;FP16;AVX2;AVX512_SKX" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_DISPATCH}")
    # else()
      # set(CPU_DISPATCH "SSE4_1;SSE4_2;AVX;FP16" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_DISPATCH}")
    # endif()
  # endif()

  if(NOT DEFINED CPU_BASELINE)
    if(APPLE)
      # MacOS X has limited set of possible supported H/W, so compiler is configured well
      set(CPU_BASELINE "DETECT" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_BASELINE}")
    elseif(X86_64)
      set(CPU_BASELINE "SSE3" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_BASELINE}")
    else()
      set(CPU_BASELINE "SSE2" CACHE STRING "${HELP_CPU_BASELINE}")
    endif()
  endif()
```

After that you simply build OpenCV using CMake. Here is how I did it:

1. Go to the *opencv-4.1.1* folder and create a new folder, let's name it **build**
2. Open a Command Prompt or PowerShell window and navigate to the **build** folder (or simply press *Shif+Right Click* and select Open PowerShell Window here)
3. Execute the following command (I've disabled building examples and test because some of them will fail) (don't forget the .. at the end of the command!) (for Visual studio 2019 replace *"Visual Studio 15 2017"* with *"Visual Studio 16 2019"* ):

   **cmake -D ENABLE_AVX=OFF -D ENABLE_AVX2=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF  -D BUILD_DOCS=OFF -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" ..**
4. After CMake finishes generating the project, open the solution file (OpenCV.sln) inside the build folder using Visual Studio
5. Build the **ALL_BUILD** project
6. One project will fail. If you look the error, it says something like *'CV_CPU_HAS_SUPPORT_AVX512_SKX': undeclared identifier* Simply replace the keyword **CV_CPU_HAS_SUPPORT_AVX512_SKX** with **false** in the code (it appears 3 times in the whole solution, replace all 3) and hit build on **ALL_BUILD** again
7. Build the **INSTALL** project. It will create a folder called **install** inside our build folder.
8. Use the freshly built OpenCV libraries, binaries and includes from the **install** folder in you project and it should work.

Comment: thanks. it works great. <3 for next-generation if they want to find out which properties their CPU supports they can use CPU-Z software.

Comment: or just immigrate to Linux.

Comment: Dirty hands of Intel.